# Two table data CRUD operation in One code first Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

i have two table in City and State.
i want to display city data + st_name from state table in one list.

i have display both table data in one list using below model but.
when i try to perform delete operation in city details its give error how to resolve this issue.??

city model:-

```
 namespace ms2app.Models.Entity
 {
   public partial class CITY_MASTER
   {
      public int CT_ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter City Code.")]
    [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "City Code should not be more than {1} characters.")]
    public string CT_CODE { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter City Name.")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "City Name should not be more than {1} characters.")]
    public string CT_NAME { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter STD Code.")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "STD Code should not be more than {1} characters.")]
    public string CT_STD_CODE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CT_ST_ID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LAST_UPDATE_DATE { get; set; }
    public bool IS_DEACTIVE { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select state.")]
    public string ST_NAME { get; set; }


}
```

}

My Controller Delete Method:-

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {

            CITY_MASTER cityMaster = db.CITY_MASTER.Find(id);
            cityMaster.IS_DEACTIVE = false;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

[image: Example]

Comment: So you dont want to delete the record? Just set that property? Firstly, find might return null, so you should probably surround the setter with an if-check

Comment: It would help if you posted the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic has no actual delete action to it.

Try this...

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {

            CITY_MASTER cityMaster = db.CITY_MASTER.Find(id);
            cityMaster.IS_DEACTIVE = false;
            db.Entry(cityMaster).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted; 
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Comment: actually i am not delete any record i just simple update record status as inactive..... IS_DEACTIVE status false for deleting City...i am not delete any record

Comment: Getting error in this statement i don't know why they                            CITY_MASTER cityMaster = db.CITY_MASTER.Find(id);